# Estimate for Integral of $L^{2}$ Functions Using Convergent Sequence of $C^{\infty}_{0}$ Functions

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

**Set-up:**

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. We consider functions from $\Omega \times [0,T]$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Let $u(x,t) \in L^{2}((0,T); H^{1}_{0, \sigma})$ such that there exists a sequence $\{u_{m}\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ which converges to $u$ weakly in $L^{2}((0,T); H^{1}_{0, \sigma})$. Here, $H^{1}_{0, \sigma} = W^{1,2}_{0, \sigma} = \{ u \in W^{1,2}_{0} : \text{div}u = 0 \}$

Let $\Phi(x,t) := \sum^{N}_{i=1} \lambda_{i}(t) \phi_{i}(x)$, where $\lambda_{i}$ are arbitrary functions in $H^{1}((s,t) ; \mathbb{R}^{1})$ for some $0 \leq s \leq t \leq T$, and $\{\phi_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty} \in H^{1}_{0, \sigma} \cap L^{n}$ such that $\text{span}\{\phi_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a complete orthonormal set dense in $L^{2}_{\sigma}$.

Now set $w_{i}(x,t) = u^{(i)}(x,t)\Phi(x,t)$, $(i=1,2,...,n)$ where $u^{(i)}$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ component of $u$. Then $w_{i} \in L^{2}(\Omega \times(s,t))$, and hence there is a sequence $\{w_{i,k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ in $C^{\infty}_{0}(\Omega \times(s,t))$ such that $w_{i,k} \rightarrow w_{i}$ in $L^{2}(\Omega \times(s,t))$.

**Problem:**

Our claim is that:

$|\int^{t}_{s} (u \cdot \nabla(u_{m} - u), \Phi) \text{d}t | \leq \sum^{n}_{i=1} \int^{t}_{s} |(u \cdot \nabla(u_{m} - u), \partial_{x_{i}}w_{i,k} )| \text{d}t \ + \ \sum^{n}_{i=1}(\int^{t}_{s} ||\nabla u_{m} - \nabla u||^{2} \text{d}t)^{1/2}(\int^{t}_{s} ||w_{i,k} - w_{i}||^{2} \text{d}t)^{1/2}$

Here $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the $L^{2}(\Omega)$ inner-product, and $||\cdot ||$ is the $L^{2}(\Omega)$ norm.

**My Attempt to Prove:**

The paper I am reading claims that the above is a simple consequence of integration by parts...

$|\int^{t}_{s} (u \cdot \nabla(u_{m} - u), \Phi) \text{d}t |$

$\leq \int^{t}_{s} |(u \cdot \nabla(u_{m} - u), \Phi)| \text{d}t$ (Just moving the absolute value inside the integral...)

$\leq \sum^{n}_{i=1} \int^{t}_{s} |(u^{(i)}\partial_{x_{i}}(u_{m} - u), \Phi)| \text{d}t $ (Using Triangle Inequality...)

$= \sum^{n}_{i=1} \int^{t}_{s} | \int_{\Omega} u^{(i)}\partial_{x_{i}}(u_{m} - u) \cdot \Phi \ \text{d}x| \ \text{d}t $ (writing out the inner-product as an integral...)

$= \sum^{n}_{i=1} \int^{t}_{s} | \int_{\Omega} \partial_{x_{i}}(u_{m} - u) \cdot u^{(i)}\Phi \ \text{d}x| \ \text{d}t $ (Moving $u^{(i)}$ to other side of dot-product)

$= \sum^{n}_{i=1} \int^{t}_{s} | \int_{\Omega} \partial_{x_{i}}(u_{m} - u) \cdot w_{i} \ \text{d}x| \ \text{d}t $ (By definition of $w_{i}$)

This tells us nothing about the relation to $w_{i,k}$ however. So I tried to obtain the desired result by assuming the next two steps are possible:

$= \sum^{n}_{i=1} \int^{t}_{s} | \int_{\Omega} \partial_{x_{i}}(u_{m} - u) \cdot ^{\text{lim}}_{k \rightarrow \infty} w_{i,k} \ \text{d}x| \ \text{d}t $

$= \sum^{n}_{i=1} \ ^{\text{lim}}_{k \rightarrow \infty}  \int^{t}_{s} | \int_{\Omega} \partial_{x_{i}}(u_{m} - u) \cdot w_{i,k} \ \text{d}x| \ \text{d}t $

However, using integration by parts here yields:

$\leq \sum^{n}_{i=1} \int^{t}_{s} |((u_{m} - u), \partial_{x_{i}}w_{i,k})| \text{d}t $

Which is clearly stronger than our actual claim. Thus I assume the abuse of limit I used above is incorrect. However, I cannot see how to arrive at the desired result. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: What is $H^{1}_{0, \sigma}$?

Comment: $H^{1}_{0, \sigma} = W^{1,2}_{0, \sigma} = \{ u \in W^{1,2}_{0} : \text{div}u = 0 \}$

Comment: In the step "writing out the inner-product as an integral", dont't you mean $\int_\Omega$ instead of $\int_s^t$?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I'll fix it right now